# Is there omission in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> 免許証ぐらいの大きさのそれは、**見た感じ**身分証みたいに見える。

Is it supposed to be 見た感じでは or something?

Also, are みたいに見える and ように見える the same?
And is there any difference with みたい/よう?
I find it confusing that there are 2 "to look like" words used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following question deals with the same sentence.

- [precision about 見た感じ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/83265/45489)

The sentences below mean more or less the same.

> 見た感じ身分証**みたいに見える**。
>
> 見た感じ**は**身分証**みたいに見える**。
>
> 見た感じ**が**身分証**みたいに見える**。
>
> 見た感じ**(は/が)**身分証**に見える**。
>
> 見た感じ**(は/が)**身分証**みたいだ**。

You can think there is an omission of は or が or even では as you guessed, but it is also possible to argue that 見た感じ is a noun that works adverbially, here modifying に見える (or みたいだ in the last sentence above).

As for みたいに見える, the difference is subtle, but as the linked answer says, it adds uncertainty to 見える. 身分証みたいに見える may be closer to *looks something like an ID* while 身分証に見える is *looks like an ID* (the speaker is to an extent sure that it is).

---

See e.g. the following for adverbial usage of nouns (although 見た感じ is not temporal obviously).

- [Adverbial Nouns and Temporal Nouns](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/23578/45489)